Git Push to GitHub Failed: remote: fatal: did not receive expected object
I cloned a repository from GitHub with a single branch (17.0) and set up my remote configurations. When I tried to push my local changes to my repository on GitHub, I received the following error:
git clone -b 17.0 --single-branch --depth 1 https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git odoo-updated

origin    https://github.com/Paulius11/odoo-test-branch.git (fetch)
origin    https://github.com/Paulius11/odoo-test-branch.git (push)
upstream  https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git (fetch)
upstream  https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git (push)


git push --set-upstream origin 17.0


Enumerating objects: 41392, done.
Counting objects: 100% (41392/41392), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (29857/29857), done.
Writing objects: 100% (41392/41392), 166.02 MiB | 146.55 MiB/s, done.
Total 41392 (delta 10093), reused 41392 (delta 10093), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (10093/10093), done.
remote: fatal: did not receive expected object 7f49d49528e0b7754362c3c2ffaae569abd7999e
error: remote unpack failed: index-pack failed
To https://github.com/Paulius11/odoo-test-branch.git
! [remote rejected]   17.0 -> 17.0 (failed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Paulius11/odoo-test-branch.git'

Any suggestions or guidance on fixing this issue would be appreciated!

Try to clone few times. This issue is because of the internet speed.
